# Except and ExceptAll functions for apache spark's dataset are giving an empty dataframe during streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

`Except` and `ExceptAll` function for apache spark's dataset are giving empty dataframe during streaming.

I am using two datasets, both are batch,
the left-one has few rows that are not present in the right-one.
Upon running it gives correct output i.e. rows that are in the left-one but not in the right one.

Now I am repeating the same in streaming, the left-one is streaming while the right-one is batch source, in this scenario, I am getting an empty dataframe upon which `dataframe.writeStream` throws an exception None.get error.

```
package exceptPOC

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object exceptPOC {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("pocExcept")
      .setMaster("local")
      .set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")

  val sparkSession = 
   SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

  val schema = new StructType()
  .add("sepal_length", DoubleType, true)
  .add("sepal_width", DoubleType, true)
  .add("petal_length", DoubleType, true)
  .add("petal_width", DoubleType, true)
  .add("species", StringType, true)

var df1 = sparkSession.readStream
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv(
    "some/path/exceptPOC/streamIris" //contains iris1
  )

var df2 = sparkSession.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv(
    "/some/path/exceptPOC/iris2.csv"
  )

val exceptDF = df1.except(df2)
exceptDF.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

Comment: need sample code snippets

Comment: with out sample its hard to guess what is happening in your side

Comment: either dataframe join from stream or normal batch dataframe the behavior  is same somehwhere you are doing the mistake. Moreover you have to ask questions with sample or example with out which no one can give right answer it will be opinion based

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram  created an added sample example same as what I use in my code, getting the same error, please have a look at it

Comment: @user3190018 created an added sample example same as what I use in my code, getting the same error, please have a look at it